# Retrieve password after hashing with random salt BCript

Tags: php, hash, yii, passwords

I cant find anywhere how to validate password after its been hashed with random salt my code to hash password:

```
    public function hashPassword($password){
        $options = [
            'cost' => 11,
            'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
        ];
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    }
```

And code to retrieve:

```
    public function validatePassword($password){
        return password_verify($this->password, self::model()->password);
    }
```

But it doesnt seem to work, maybe anyone can let me know why?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using the `$password` parameter in your validatePassword function. Note: `$password` should be the plain text password entered and the second parameter should contain the hashed version you previously stored. Try this:

```
public function validatePassword($password){
    return password_verify($password, self::model()->password);
}
```

Also, it's best to not handle salting yourself. Just use the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` option and do not salt. PHP will handle it. You can use `password_needs_rehash()` to check if you need to rehash the password if a PHP version upgrade changes the default.

Answer (score 0):

Hash it again exactly the same way and compare the 2 strings. This is the way most passwords are compared.

Comment: Note that you have to save the salt generated for each password to be able to use the same one when comparing (this or use a unique salt for all passwords, which is safe enough if it's kept secret)

Comment: Exactly, the whole point is to never store the actual password in case of a security breach.

Comment: So that means I have to save salt.. So is it a secure practice to have table of salts that contains user id and salt for each user?

Comment: I usually define 1 salt for the entire application. The main reason for the salt is to protect against rainbow tables. Having 1 salt for the entire application (make it a big salt) should be enough. You can also use individual salts from the user table, a field that never changes, like the id (might be too low), or the timestamp from the join date.